# Retrieve links stored in DB and show it in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

Need a small help.
I'm having a table which is having links stored in some of the columns. I'm binding the table with a GridView present on my page. I need the cells of GridView to act as a link.

I have tried this code.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvAutomationTesting" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link 01" SortExpression="Link01">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lb01" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link01") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

The output which i'm getting is having a  tag but without href attribute because of which even if i try to click it is not redirecting to the desired page.

Comment: I have updated the post with the code i have written. Please check and help.

Answer (score 0):

hope below code snippets will help you, using templatefield you can assign the link button to grid column

---

```html
<div>
            <asp:GridView id="mygrid">
                    <asp:TemplateField headertext="number" datatype="string" filterexpression="CUSTOMERNUMBER"
                      sortexpression="CUSTOMERNUMBER"> 
            <itemtemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "CUSTOMERNUMBER") %>' />
                <%--CUSTOMERNUMBER is your DB column name--%>
            </itemtemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            
            <asp:boundfield headertext="Customer" datafield="CUSTOMERNAME" datatype="string" filterexpression="CUSTOMERNAME"
                             sortexpression="CUSTOMERNAME"> 
            </asp:boundfield>
                 
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

Comment: I tried your code and updated the post. Please check one more time as i'm not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb01" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link01") %>' />
```

by

```
<a ID="lb01" runat="server" href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link01")' ><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link01") %> </a>
```